# Pointer is assigned to wrong local variable

Tags: c++, pointers

I've just started to learn c++ and I have some example code right here that shows a problem with a local variable and a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* f1 (int n) {
   int* p = &n;
   return p;
}//f1

void f2 (int na) {
   int nb = na;
}//f2

int main () {
   int* nn = f1 (101);
   f2 (2002);
   cout << *nn << endl;
}//main

/* 
2002 // output MinGW 6.2.0
*/
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find an explanation why this happens. As far as I understood p is returned to the caller so nn should equal 101 but it somehow gets assigned to the parameter that was given to f2? I'm really confused. I'm also sorry if this is a really basic question.

Comment: the variable `n` in `f1()` is a local copy. When `f1()` exits, it no longer exists, and the newly created pointer points to nothing sensible anymore, which makes this undefined Behaviour. The fact that the parameter from `f2` *happens* to be the new value at that location is pretty much random chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This instruction:

```
int* p = &n;
```

assigns a pointer to a *local, automatic* variable `n`.

That variable is destroyed at the end of `f1()`, so as soon as you execute

```
 return p;
```

the pointer becomes **invalid**. Storing it in `nn` and using a pointed value by dereferencing it with `*nn` triggers an **Undefined Behavior** - you can't know what happens after.

What actually happens *in your specific case* (credit to @Caleth) is probably that the `n` variable is stored on the machine stack, and the very same location is then used by `na` of `f2()`, hence it gets overwritten with the `2002` value of the parameter to `f2`.

But **never** rely on such effects! Variables needn't be allocated in the same manner for different functions, e.g. stack frames can be stacked one by one and freed several subsequent calls later (I've seen such behavior in - IIRC - a Watcom C compiler many years ago), or `na` could be allocated in the microprocessor's register. Anyway even if they are located on the stack and in the same place of the stack, they needn't keep the same value! The stack can be used by other mechanisms, not necessarily visible in your source code.

P.S.
The same happens in C, not just in C++. Using `cout` with its `<<` operators doesn't matter in the problem.

Comment: "What actually happens is" -> "An explanation for the particular behaviour you *observed that time* is"

Answer (score 0):

As [CiaPan notes in his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424322/2445184), you are in undefined behavior territory as soon as you are returning a pointer to a local variable. Here is what actually happens under the hood: Your local variables are stored on the function call stack, which changes state at every function call/return. When a function returns, it generally does not clear the stack memory that it used, so it may appear to remain valid. But by the language standard, that memory pretty much ceases to exist, and any pointer pointing into it becomes invalid immediately. I hope the ASCII art will help you understand what's really going on.

```
Before call of f1():
| main(): nn |
| ?????????? |
           |
           v
          ???

During execution of f1():
| main(): nn | f1(): n  | f1(): p  |
| ?????????? |      101 |       &n |
           |         ^          /
           v          \________/
          ???

After f1() returns (nn is invalid as n does not exist anymore):
| main(): nn | unused space        |
|    invalid |      101 |       &n |
           \         ^    
            \________/

During execution of f2() (nn is still invalid, but seems to point to na now):
| main(): nn | f2(): na | f2(): nb |
|    invalid |     2002 |     2002 |
           \         ^    
            \________/

After f2() returns, nn is still invalid, but points to the memory that was once occupied by na:
| main(): nn | unused space        |
|    invalid |     2002 |     2002 |
           \         ^    
            \________/
```